# Cant access remote management interface

Tags: cisco, routing, switching, management, cisco-asr

[image]

The data link is completely okay. I can access MGMT IPs of routers (10.0.0.2 |10.0.0.4) from 3750 but not from PC. I can access 3750 MGMT IP (10.0.0.1) from PC . Any idea why ?

Note : All management links are in same vlan in 3750

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following:

- Plug an ethernet cable from the cisco 3750 into the ASR's `MGMT ETHERNET` port
- Ensure the ASR `MGMT ETHERNET` cables are in `mgmt_vlan` on the 3750
- Ensure the `mgmt_vlan` with 10.0.0.0 is in the Cisco 3750's global routing table
- Put an IP address on the `MGMT ETHERNET` GigabitEthernet0 port of the ASR's RP

After you've checked those things, then add this command on each of the ASRs...

```
ip route vrf Mgmt-intf 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
```

This is the [Cisco ASR1000 doc ref](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/configuration/guide/chassis/asrswcfg/Management_Ethernet.html#pgfId-1060607):

[image: Mgmt-intf]

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer.  ASR management interfaces are VRF-locked into Mgmt-intf, and so ignore all global routing statics like you've probably already created.  Also be aware that there are some limitations around using the Mgmt interface on an ASR -- namely that you can't send NetFlow statistics out of it.